# Determine whether integer is between two other integers

Tags: python

How do I determine whether a given integer is between two other integers (e.g. greater than/equal to `10000` and less than/equal to `30000`)?

Comment: Comparisons can be chained https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Answer (score 1554, accepted):

```
if 10000 <= number <= 30000:
    pass
```

For details, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Comment: Python is so nice :). And to be redundant: this is called "interval comparison."

Comment: What is the speed difference between this and `if number in range(10000, 30001)` as suggested by other solution? Additionally, is it faster or slower when using `set` instead of `range`?

Comment: @MikeC With the interval comparison `number` is first compared against `10000`. If  it's less than `10000` the expression is immediately short-circuited and the second comparison is not checked. The complexity is `O(1)`.  `in range(0, n)` instead generates the entire sequence of numbers and then iterates through it. The complexity is `O(n)`. The complexity of `in set(range(0, n))` is still `O(n)` because building a set has a time complexity of `O(n)` 
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

Comment: @MikeC Try to run in your shell:
`> python -m timeit '10000 <= 10 <= 30000'`
`> python -m timeit '10 in range(10000, 30001)'`
`> python -m timeit '10 in set(range(10000, 30001))'`

Comment: @SungWonCho, make sure to use `xrange` instead of `range` if you are testing on Python2

Comment: looks like in python3.5.2, range is ~10x slower than the if statement, with speed  constant in regard to range check value...thus most likely difference due to function overhead.

Comment: @SungCho not only ```if number in range(10000, 30001)``` is slow, it'll eat up a lot of unnecessary memory. it'll create all those numbers in a list and make a linear search, range is meant for loops where the index is needed.

Comment: @IanElvister That's incorrect. `range` no longer creates a list in Python 3. See [Why is `10**15 in range(10**15+1)` so fast in Python 3?](/q/30081275/4518341)

Answer (score 133):

```
>>> r = range(1, 4)
>>> 1 in r
True
>>> 2 in r
True
>>> 3 in r
True
>>> 4 in r
False
>>> 5 in r
False
>>> 0 in r
False
```

Comment: Wow I always thought `range` (or `xrange` in python2) returns a generator thus you cannot repeatedly test on it.

Comment: If the test range is huge (e.g. `range(1000000000)`), using `xrange` in python2 is pretty slow. But `range` in python3 doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: @yegle range (in python3) does not return an iterator, it returns a range object. range objects can be iterated more than once.

Comment: Its important to so keep in mind that `4 in range(1,4)` is False. So better use the `1 >= r <= 4` as it avoids possible errors by newcomers

Comment: `1.5 in r` gives `False`, even in 3.4. This answer is only good for integers.

Comment: @jpmc26, good point. On the other hand you can specify a step size, so `range(1, n, 2)` lets you test for odd numbers.

Comment: @tripplet, you made the same error as the OP!, It should be `1 <= r <= 4`

Comment: `timeit i=100; i in xrange(1000)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 µs per loop

In [16]: timeit i=100; 1 <=i<=1000
10000000 loops, best of 3: 39.2 ns per loop
`

Plus the bigger  i the longer it works .

Comment: (1.) bad performance (as others have pointed out this syntax **looks good** but can take a long time to execute because it is O(n) operations vs the `if a <= x <= b`...) (2.) doesn't work for `float` types (3.) the range test is not-inclusive... so many developers may introduce bugs because they expect inclusive range

Comment: `x = 12000
RANGE_MIN = 10000 
RANGE_MAX = 30000 
if x == np.clip(x, RANGE_MIN, RANGE_MAX): 
    print("x is OK")`

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith, I would say `x in range(...)` is not actually exhausting the range iterator according to this CPython implementation (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dc31334ab1b43225b65358fa361b46c22918b400/Objects/rangeobject.c#L383)

Answer (score 71):

Use `if number >= 10000 and number <= 30000:`.  Alternately, Python has a shorthand for this sort of thing, `if 10000 <= number <= 30000:`.

Comment: ... *this sort of thing* is typically called [*chained comparison*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 40):

To check that the number is in the range 10000 - 30000, use the Python interval comparison:

```
if 10000 <= number <= 30000:
    print ("you have to pay 5% taxes")
```

This Python feature is further described [in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: You can also use it for the initial comparison, although it's as useless:
if 10000 <= 30000 <= number:

Answer (score 30):

There are **two ways** to compare three integers and check whether **b** is between **a** and **c**:

```
if a < b < c:
    pass
```

and

```
if a < b and b < c:
    pass
```

The first one looks like more readable, but the **second one runs faster**.

Let's compare using **dis.dis**:

```
>>> dis.dis('a < b and b < c')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('a < b < c')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             14 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

and using **timeit**:

```
~$ python3 -m timeit "1 < 2 and 2 < 3"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0366 usec per loop

~$ python3 -m timeit "1 < 2 < 3"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0396 usec per loop
```

also, you may use **range**, as suggested before, however it is much more slower.

Answer (score 14):

```
if number >= 10000 and number <= 30000:
    print ("you have to pay 5% taxes")
```

Answer (score 14):

Define the range between the numbers:

```
r = range(1,10)
```

Then use it:

```
if num in r:
    print("All right!")
```

Comment: `range` doesn't count the  last value **10** in your case .  `range(1,11)` is correct, if  you need  to compare between 1 and 10

Answer (score 13):

Below are few possible ways, ordered from best to worse performance (i.e first one will perform best)

```
     # Old school check
     if 10000 <= b and b <=30000:
        print ("you have to pay 5% taxes")
     # Python range check
     if 10000 <= number <= 30000:
        print ("you have to pay 5% taxes")
     # As suggested by others but only works for integers and is slow
     if number in range(10000,30001):
        print ("you have to pay 5% taxes")
```

Comment: `in range(...)` is quite fast, see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/5320906).

Answer (score 11):

Python lets you just *write* what you mean in words:

```
if number in xrange(10000, 30001): # ok you have to remember 30000 + 1 here :)
```

In Python3, use `range` instead of `xrange`.

edit: People seem to be more concerned with microbench marks and how cool chaining operations. My answer is about defensive (less attack surface for bugs) programming.

As a result of a claim in the comments, I've added the micro benchmark here for Python3.5.2

```
$ python3.5 -m timeit "5 in range(10000, 30000)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.266 usec per loop
$ python3.5 -m timeit "10000 <= 5 < 30000"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0327 usec per loop
```

If you are worried about performance, you could compute the range once

```
$ python3.5 -m timeit -s "R=range(10000, 30000)" "5 in R"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0551 usec per loop
```

Comment: xrange is deprecated in Python 3, unfortunately.

Comment: @apraetor, yes use `range(10000, 30001)` in Python3. It doesn't create a list

Comment: your solution will iterate over 20 thousand integers. using <= and <= is much more efficient.

Comment: @JBChouinard, you are absolutely incorrect. `xrange` in Python2, or `range` in Python3 have membership tests. Try it yourself if you don't believe. `<=` is only more efficient because it doesn't create a range object. Both ways as O(1). The point is the OP _was_ **trying to do it your way and ended up with a bug**. Fast code that is wrong is worse.

Comment: on an i5, (i)python 3.5:
    %timeit 5 in range(10000, 30000)
    1000 loops, best of 3: 451 µs per loop.
    %timeit 10000 <= 5 <= 30000
    10000000 loops, best of 3: 59.4 ns per loop.
that's a factor of over 7000

Comment: @tback I reran your tests and got ```timeit 5 in range(10000, 30000)``` ```428 ns ± 19.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)``` and ```%timeit 10000 <= 5 <= 30000``` ```71.6 ns ± 4.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)``` on an i7 python 3.6.3 so only 6x slower.

Answer (score 9):

While `10 <= number <= 20` works in Python, I find this notation using `range()` more readable:

```py
if number in range(10, 21):
    print("number is between 10 (inclusive) and 21 (exclusive)")
else:
    print("outside of range!")
```

Keep in mind that the 2nd, upper bound parameter is not included in the range set as can be verified with:

```py
>>> list(range(10, 21))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

However prefer the `range()` approach only if it's not running on some performance critical path. A single call is still fast enough for most requirements, but if run 10,000,000 times, we clearly notice nearly 3 times slower performance compared to `a <= x < b`:

```
> { time python3 -c "for i in range(10000000): x = 50 in range(1, 100)"; } 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^.*cpu \(.*\) total$/\1/p'
1.848

> { time python3 -c "for i in range(10000000): x = 1 <= 50 < 100"; } 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^.*cpu \(.*\) total$/\1/p'
0.630
```

Comment: Note that `10 <= 10.5 <= 20` is True while `10.5 in range(10, 21)` is False; depending on the situation, that may or may not be what you intend

Comment: While this is true for floats, OP precisely asked about integer comparison.

Comment: Ah, so they have; in that case, the two expressions are indeed equivalent

Comment: If the bounds are pre-defined, there is no need to construct a new `range` object each time. Still slower than the `<= <=` construct, but it takes only 1.5× the time on my machine, not 3×.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there are 3 non-negative integers: `a`, `b`, and `c`. Mathematically speaking, if we want to determine if `c` is between `a` and `b`, inclusively, one can use this formula:

> (c - a) * (b - c) >= 0

or in Python:

```
> print((c - a) * (b - c) >= 0)
True
```

Comment: this is the most obtuse possible way to do this and is less performant at the same time

Comment: This is an efficient solution if we want to test a < c < b or b < c < a.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding a solution that nobody mentioned yet, using Interval class from sympy library:

```
from sympy import Interval

lower_value, higher_value = 10000, 30000
number = 20000

 # to decide whether your interval shhould be open or closed use left_open and right_open 
interval = Interval(lower_value, higher_value, left_open=False, right_open=False)
if interval.contains(number):
    print("you have to pay 5% taxes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the output to print the given statement if and only if the number falls between 10,000 and 30,000.

Code should be;

```
if number >= 10000 and number <= 30000:
    print("you have to pay 5% taxes")
```

Comment: This answer has already been suggested. What does your answer add to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You used >=30000, so if number is 45000 it will go into the loop, but we need it to be more than 10000 but less than 30000. Changing it to <=30000 will do it!

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple function; it checks if `A` is between `B` and `C` (`B` and `C` may not be in the right order):

```
def isBetween(A, B, C):
    Mi = min(B, C)
    Ma = max(B, C)
    return Mi <= A <= Ma
```

so `isBetween(2, 10, -1)` is the same as `isBetween(2, -1, 10)`.

Answer (score -8):

The condition should be,

```
if number == 10000 and number <= 30000:
     print("5% tax payable")
```

reason for using `number == 10000` is that if number's value is 50000 and if we use `number >= 10000` the condition will pass, which is not what you want.

Comment: This will fail for 10001, for example, though. He wants numbers between 10000 and 30000. Your condition will only work for number == 10000.

Comment: This will fail for the user's requirement. This is not an appropriate solution.