# Return if a number is between two values [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quite a simple question, but I have no clue on how to implement this.

Essentially:

```
>>> r = range(4,-1)
>>> 3 in r
False
>>> q = range(-1,4)
>>> 3 in q
True
```

As you can see, I have the same bounds, -1 and 4, and the same test value, so how do I say that '3' is between'-1' and '4' when I do not know the order that they are given to me in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i check if int is between the range of two numbers (tried various solutions before)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/how-do-i-check-if-int-is-between-the-range-of-two-numbers-tried-various-solutio)

Comment: From the above, this is a valid boolean in python: `1 <= r <= 10`

Comment: The bounds aren't the same - the stop value isn't included

Comment: Python has `min()` and `max()`, which could be put to good use here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not sort the bounds first?

```
r = range(*sorted((4, -1)))
q = range(*sorted((-1, 4)))
```

Comment: Landed here searching something similar but for float dtypes (if float is between floats). Since floats' range can be infinite, it's best to just use sorted and access the values' index. `s = sorted(value1, value2)` and then use something like pandas Series between: `if pd.Series.between(4.21, s[0], s[1]):`

Answer (score 7):

`range` doesn't do what you think it does.

It creates a list; it's not a numeric range (edit: actually it does in Python 3).

Just imagine a case, when the `lowerEnd` is -20000 and the `upperEnd` is +20000. Using the `range( -20000, 20000 )` and comparing `num` in such a `range()` is a waste of both memory and CPU-power.

It is quite enough to compare a `num` against `lowerEnd` & `upperEnd` limit

You want to check:

```
num = 3
print(-1 < num < 4)
```

Comment: no it doesn't (return a list). The question is tagged Python3. range returns a "range object"

Comment: You can chain the comparisons  `-1 < num <=4`. There is an implicit `and`. This doesn't help if you don't know which bound is bigger/smaller though anyway

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try printing each step of your code snippet ? The code becomes self-explanatory to an extent. `range()` returns a list actually. So when this line is executed

```
r = range(4,-1)
print r 

[]   ## returned an empty list so which is why 3 in r returns False.
```

But when you execute like this

```
q = range(-1,4)
print q

[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]  ## Returned a list with 3 in it so 3 in q returns True
```

Now you want to check falls in range then you can do like this

```
if -1<= 3 <= 4:
   print "Falls in the range"
else:
   print "not in range"
```

output:

```
Falls in the range
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a if statement to find the order

```
if c > d:
    c, d = d, c 

r = range(c, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
r = list(xrange(4,-1,-1))
3 in r

True

q = list(xrange(-1,4,1))
3 in q

True
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `range` builtin needs a little while to be grasped but when working with the interactive interpreter `help(range)` is always a helping hand...

#### Python 2.x

```
>>> print range(4,-1)
>>> print range(-1,4)
```

#### Pyton 3.x

```
>>> print(list(range(4,-1)))
>>> print(list(range(-1,4)))
```

but there is a problem (perhaps not with your specific issue) even if you add a step argument to the invocation of range (example for Python 2.x)

```
>>> print range(4, -1, -1)
>>> print range(-1,4)
```

as you can see, the two ranges are not the same: the `start` argument is in the list, the `stop` one is not.

---

You can think of it in these terms: "in a `range`, the `stop` argument means *stop before*".

---

Answer (score 0):

As answered by 101 and d-coder, your question to find a value *between* two other values should be constructed using  `<`  or `<=` operators, depending on what you want.  Assuming that you know that r is a simple collection, like a list or tuple or range, but you don't know it's ordering, you could write:

```
>>> r = (-1,4,2,3,0)
>>> min(r) < 3 < max(r)
True
>>> min(r) < 2.5 < max(r)
True
```

The `in` operator on the other hand will test whether your value is one of the values in the list

```
>>> 3 in r
True
>>> 2.5 in r
False
```

Finally, your first example failed because you did not specify a negative step when trying to define 'r' as a decreasing sequence. Here's an example where I'll specify a step size of -2 as the 3rd argument of `range()`:

```
>>> a = range(4,-1)
>>> print a
[]
>>> b = range(5,-1,-2)
>>> print b
[5, 3, 1]
>>> 3 in a
False
>>> 3 in b
True
```

Comment: So, you just took all the other answers and combined them into a new one? This does not bring anything to the table IMO.

Comment: This answer is actually useful and lays out clearly an approach that had only been hinted at in comments. It's also the only one provided that works for non-integers.