# python integer between two values

Tags: python

I found a thread on this but am not having any luck getting it working.

```
min = 9
max = 10
a = ['8','9','10','11']

for x in a:
    if max >= x > min:
        print 'one'
    else:
        d = (max >= x > min)
        print d, x
    if (x > min >= max):
   #if (min < x >= max):
        print x
    else:
        print x, ' is equal to or greater than', max
```

Outputs:

```
False 8
8  is equal to or greater than 10
False 9
9  is equal to or greater than 10
False 10
10  is equal to or greater than 10
False 11
11  is equal to or greater than 10
```

this thread [working code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/how-do-i-check-whether-an-int-is-between-the-two-numbers) indicates syntax needs to be:

```
if 10000 <= number <= 30000:
pass
```

I've tried every combination of signs I can think of, and the returns are always True or False for all, which is wrong.

I've also tried this (much longer) code:

```
min = 9
max = 10
a = ['8','9','10','11']

for x in a:
    print 'X is:', x
    if int(x) == max:
        print 'max found:', x
    elif int(x) < max:
        if int(x) > min:
            print 'min:', x
    elif int(x) < min:
        print 'under range', x
    else:
        print 'out of range', x
```

with output also unexpected, since I expect to catch all cases:

```
X is: 8
X is: 9
X is: 10
max found: 10
X is: 11
out of range 11
```

Ugh!  How can I check all items 'properly' and return under, at, over my min, max?

Comment: You're comparing strings and integers.

Comment: Thanks!  Check the second bit of code.

Comment: There aren't any integers that are > min and < max. Perhaps you meant `>=` and `<=`?

Comment: wait, you want a integer between 9 and 10?? you know that there is none, right?

Comment: Doh.  I had min set to 8 before I started pulling hair out.  Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare int, int or str, str. Past that I would recommend `bisect` which gives you insertion points.

For example:

```
import bisect

minint, maxint = 9, 10
a = ['8','9','10','11']

b = [int(x) for x in a]

minidx = bisect.bisect_left(b, minint)
maxidx = bisect.bisect_left(b, maxint)

print('below:', a[0:minidx])
print('between:', a[minidx:maxidx])
print('above:', a[maxidx:])
```

which outputs:

```
below: ['8']
between: ['9']
above: ['10', '11']
```

Depending on how you define the comparison `<=` or `<` at each of the ends you need to apply either `bisect_left` or `bisect_right`

If we change the first `bisect` to `right`:

```
import bisect

minint, maxint = 9, 10
a = ['8','9','10','11']

b = [int(x) for x in a]

minidx = bisect.bisect_right(b, minint)
maxidx = bisect.bisect_left(b, maxint)

print('below:', a[0:minidx])
print('between:', a[minidx:maxidx])
print('above:', a[maxidx:])
```

The output changes and shows that nothing is in between 9 and 10

```
below: ['8', '9']
between: []
above: ['10', '11']
```

The docs (for 2.7): https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Comment: Nice!  I've no experience with bisect.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: Apart from the type error in my first code chunk - it turns out I don't actually need to check within, only case A or B.  This code does what it's supposed to do:

    if len(rec) == max_rec_len: 
        authored.append(rec)
    elif len(rec) == min_rec_len:
        records.append(rec)