# Having trouble with Validation

Tags: python, validation

I want to validate that the class is a number between 1 and 6. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
print("What is your name?") #Asking User Name
name = input().title() 
class_name = input("What class are you in? ")
print (name, ", Welcome to the Maths Test")
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/how-do-i-check-whether-an-int-is-between-the-two-numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using an if condition which checks the value your entered is between 1 and 6:-

```
if not int(class_name, 16)>1 and int(class_name, 16) < 6:
    print "Your validation message"
```