# How can I reference a list element in this function?

Tags: python, list

I've managed to get this function to iterate over the list. What I want is a way to include the current list element in the output string. ie. `(raw_input("Enter the number of hours the employee worked on : "))` showing Monday or Tuesday or which ever element the function is at.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

day = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

def hours():
    while True:
        try:
            hours = int(raw_input("Enter the number of hours the employee worked on : "))
            if (hours >=0) and (hours <=24):
                return hours
            else:
                print ("Please enter a whole number that is more than zero & less than 24")
        except ValueError:
            print ("Please enter a whole number that is more than zero & less than 24")
            continue


for i in day:
    print hours()
```

Comment: in case I have any more questions. can someone also explain why my code is all bunched up like that

Comment: you should consider to read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). That being said what do you mean by  *include the current list element in the output string*? Please add the expected output to your question

Comment: you have to pass a parameter to hours function : def hour(variable):

Comment: what version your using?

Comment: judging from the parentheses in print, i would say is 3.x

Comment: i'm using 2.7. what I want is for user input for each day of the week. i.e. enter hours for mon, then tues, wed & so on. i'm not sure how to reference the list element in the input string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the weekday in your output you can use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function like so:

```
"Enter ... worked on {0} : ".format(day)
```

and pass the `day` into your `hours()` function:

```
print hours(i)
```

Of course, you have to define your function to accept that one new parameter:

```
def hours(day):
    ...
```

So your function with a little bit of clean-up looks as follows. Notice that the list of weekdays has a capitalized name as per [convention for constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants), and that the [range check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/how-do-i-check-whether-an-int-is-between-the-two-numbers) is simplified. Also, in general, if you have to type the same line of code more than once it might make sense to rethink the structure of your code:

```
def hours(day):
    while True:
        try:
            prompt = "Enter the number of hours the employee worked on {0}: ".format(day)
            hours = int(raw_input(prompt))
            if 0 <= hours <= 24:
                return hours
        except ValueError:
            pass # Silently catch failure.
        print "Please enter a whole number that is more than zero & less than 24"

WEEKDAYS = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
for day in WEEKDAYS:
    print hours(day)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3. Just make it `hours = int(input("Enter the number of hours the employee worked on: "))`