# interval comparison in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do an interval comparison similar to what is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/how-do-i-check-whether-an-int-is-between-the-two-numbers) as `10000 <= number <= 30000` but I'm trying to do it in a data frame. For example, below is my sample data and I want to get all rows where latitude is within 1 of my predefined coordinates.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[5,7, 'wolf'],
              [5,6,'cow'],
              [8, 2, 'rabbit'],
              [5, 3, 'rabbit'],
              [3, 2, 'cow'],
              [7, 5, 'rabbit']],
              columns = ['lat', 'long', 'type'])

coords = [4,7]

viewShort = df[(coords[0] - 1) <= df['lat'] <= (coords[0] + 1)]
```

unfortunately, I get a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` when I write it that way.

I realize that I could write it like this instead

```
viewLong = df[((coords[0] - 1) <= df['lat']) & (df['lat'] <= (coords[0] + 1))]
```

but I have to write a lot of these things, so I was trying to make it a bit more compact. What am I doing wrong in the `viewShort` example? Or is this just not possible with pandas and I have to write it the long way?

Thank you!

Sidenote: the correct `viewShort` data frame should have four rows:

```
[5,7,'wolf'],
[5,6,'cow'],
[5,3,'rabbit'],
[3,2,'cow']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chained comparisons are not supported. You need to do:

```
df[df['lat'].between(coords[0] - 1, coords[0] + 1)]  # inclusive=True by default
Out: 
   lat  long    type
0    5     7    wolf
1    5     6     cow
3    5     3  rabbit
4    3     2     cow
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I think the .between() is clean enough for my purposes.