# Greater or Smaller than in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program which calculates overall scores and outputs a grading system

Say Pass, Merit, Distinction depending on which grade they got.

I've tried the code below but it's no use. Also tried using and/or statements but no luck.

```
number = input("Enter a number: ")

if number < 40: 
    print("Failed")

elif number > 40 < 50:
    print("Pass")

elif number > 50 < 60:
    print("Merit")

else:
    print("Distinction")
```

So I'm basically trying to get this to work, however the conditional statements aren't working and can't properly categorise the mark.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by `number > 50 > 60:`

Comment: so if the inputted number is bigger than 50  but smaller than 60. Sorry. I've just noticed the error as i've typed this. haha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628825

Answer (score 1):

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if number < 40: 
    print("Failed")
elif number < 50:
    print("Pass")
elif number < 60:
    print("Merit")
else:
    print("Distinction")
```

The conditions are *chained*. If you ever reach `elif number < 50`, that means the previous `if number < 40` must have been `False` (i.e. the number is >= 40). You do not need to retest this condition again.

The code does: "Is it under 40? No? Is it under 50 then? No? Is it under 60 then? No? Wow, it's over 60 then!" Or if it is, say, under 50, that's where the comparisons stop.

For the sake of completeness, the correct way to write a chained comparison would be:

```
if 40 < number < 50
```

This tests whether the number is between 40 and 50.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of input is of type `str`, so to compare it with numbers, it should be first converted to type `int`

```
number = 0
try:
    number = int(input("Enter a number:"))
except:
    print("Please input an integer")
    exit(1)

# Now write your conditions     
if number > 100 or number < 0:
    print("Sorry grades can only be between 0 and 100")
elif number < 40:
    print("Failed")
elif number < 50:
    print("Pass")
elif number< 60:
    print("Merit")
else:
    print("Distinction")
```

Comment: Valid point, but the conditions could still be simplified. See comments to other answers.

Comment: The first condition can never be true.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognized it. Fixed it now

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly your conditions, the code should be like the following one:

```
number = input("Enter a number: ")

if number < 40: 
    print("Failed")

elif number >= 40 and number < 50:
    print("Pass")

elif number >= 50 and  number< 60:
    print("Merit")

else:
    print("Distinction")
```

Comment: You can omit the redundant >= test.

Comment: Probably i miss the point, but why? do you mean that i can remove >=40 and >=50?

Comment: Yes. Because you’ve already ruled out that condition by the previously chained `if` statement. It wouldn’t go into the `elif` if the number was smaller than 40.

Comment: Ok, but what happen if user inserts 50? the code will print Distinction, but the correct result is Merit right?

Comment: Why would it print “Distinction”?

Comment: If i remove all equals symbol from the code, number = 50 is not included in any if condition, but only in the else branch...

Comment: `if number < 40: ... elif number < 50: ...`. When you enter 39, the first condition applies, when you enter 40 it falls through to the next `elif`. You don't have to *retest* the (reverse of the) previous condition.