# how to check if mouse in field with python?

Tags: python-3.x, mouse

I want something to happen when my mouse is in the field, for example.

```
if(x=(100 up to 200) and y=(100 up to 200):
```

This means it will work if x = 102 and y = 199 for example.

I tried to do it with `import pyautogui`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/determine-whether-integer-is-between-two-other-integers

Comment: ok, i will try it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean?

```
if (x in range(100, 200)) and (y in range(100, 200)):
    pass
```