# Faster way to find if a number is between two number in Python

Tags: python

Please is there a faster way to find out if a number is between two numbers. My current code is below. Thanks

```
lists = [2.3, 4, 3,5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 6, 8]
newlist = []
a = 2
b = 7
for i in lists:
    if min(a, b) < i < max(a, b):
        newlist.append(i)
print(newlist)
```

Comment: How have you determined that this is too slow? You could calculate the `min` and `max` outside the loop, but that will be a pretty small improvement. Also, if the list is always sorted, you can exit early.

Comment: This should be pretty good already

Comment: I think this is already the fastest code ever written in Python.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it is fast enough too. Just checking. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `a` and `b` don't change, so you don't need to repeatedly call `min` and `max` inside the loop. Just put `if b < a: a, b = b, a` before the loop; then `if a < i < b` will suffice inside.

Comment: why don't you first take out `min`, `max` values instead of using it inside loop at each iteration? `minValue,maxValue = min(a,b), max(a,b)`
`

Comment: Just finding out the maximum and minimum everytime inside the loop, just take those two functions outside the loop.

Comment: This has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/determine-whether-integer-is-between-two-other-integers

Comment: You might be able to improve it if the list is sorted.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time if `lists` is sorted? If so, you can stop the iteration early once `i` is greater than the maximum. You can also use binary search to find the first item greater than the minimum. Whether these would be worthwhile optimizations depends on how long the list is, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lists = [2.3, 4, 3,5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 6, 8]
newlist = []
a = 2
b = 7
minimum = min(a, b)
maximum = max(a, b)
for i in lists:
    if minimum < i < maximum:
        newlist.append(i)
print(newlist)
```

This will make things faster as we are not computing minimum and maximum everytime when the loop runs and conditions are checked.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```py
a, b = min(a, b), max(a, b)
newlist = [x for x in lists if a < x < b]
```

With 100000 iterations, I found it 3 times faster than the original code. Using list comprehension instead of `if` helps a little, but most improvements come from pre-defining max and min before list comprehension (or `if`);

- 0.1944 sec.: list comprehension + min & max predefined
- 0.2672 sec.: if + min & max predefined
- 0.5600 sec.: original (if + min & max at each iteration)

Answer (score 0):

When looking for where your code is slow, [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) built-in module is handy. Here we can use it following way

```
import cProfile as profile
def func():
    lists = [2.3, 4, 3,5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 6, 8]
    newlist = []
    a = 2
    b = 7
    for i in lists:
        if min(a, b) < i < max(a, b):
            newlist.append(i)
    print(newlist)
profile.run('func()')
```

output is

```
[2.3, 4, 3, 5.5, 6.5, 6]
         27 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <stdin>:1(func)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.min}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

As you might deduce `max` and `min` was used 8 times each but in this case once for `min` and once for `max` would be enough. Sample data is too tiny to say anything useful about time of execution of components. If you wish you might use more data (longer `lists`) and look for results.