# Python: if-else statement, printing 'Weird' if a given integer is odd or it's even but within a particular range shown below, and 'Not Weird' if not

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to create an if-else function which will print 'Weird' if an integer n is odd, 'Not Weird' if it's even and between 2 and 5 inclusive, 'Weird' if it's  lies between 6 and 20 and not weird if it's an even integer more than 20. I tried the following code but it wouldn't run, can you tell me what the issue is?

```
#!/bin/python

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

if n % 2 = 1:
    print ("Weird")

else:
    if n range(2,5):
        print:("Not Weird")

    else:
        if n range(6,20):
            print("Weird")

        else:
            print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: `==` is for equality, not `=`. This is pretty basic syntax issue. Get a proper IDE and it will highlight these issues.

Comment: `if n range(2,5):` makes no sense. I assume you meant to do `if n in range(2,5):` [Determine Whether Integer Is Between Two Other Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/determine-whether-integer-is-between-two-other-integers)

Comment: _I tried the following code but it wouldn't run, can you tell me what the issue is?_ Always post the full traceback you get. It helps us to help you and is actually telling what the problem is. As mentioned by @Goion you want to use `in` - membership operator.

Comment: you somewhere copy/pasted `if __name__ == '__main__':` but you either did not understand what it is good for or you have serveral IndentationErrors to make it work as it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps! If this is not exactly what you were looking for, you can still use my code but reorganize the parts.

```
n = int(input('Write your number : ').strip())

if n % 2 == 1:
    #n is odd
    print ("Weird")

else:
    #n is even
    if 2 <= n <= 5:
        #n between 2 and 5 inclusive
        print("Not Weird")

    elif 6 <= n <= 20:
        #n between 6 and 20 inclusive
        print("Weird")

    elif n > 20:
        #n greater than 20
        print("Not Weird")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't defined a function.
2. You forgot to use the word `in` to check if something is in a range.
3. You need to use the `==` operator to check for equality (not `=` which is assignment).

You also don't really need ranges here, just simple inequality operators.  You also don't need any of the modules you imported.

```
def is_weird(n: int) -> bool:
    """Calculates whether or not a positive integer is 'weird'."""
    if n % 2 == 1:
        return True
    if n <= 5:
        return False
    if n <= 20:
        return True
    return False

def print_weirdness(n: int) -> None:
    """Prints whether or not a positive integer is 'weird'."""
    print("Weird" if is_weird(n) else "Not Weird")

n = int(input().strip())
print_weirdness(n)
```