# 4.5.1 Detect Number Range Zybook

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write an expression that prints "Eligible" if user_age is between 18 and 25 inclusive.
Ex: 17 prints "Ineligible", 18 prints "Eligible".

```
user_age = int(input())

if ''' Your solution goes here ''':
    print('Eligible')
else:
    print('Ineligible')
```

I keep putting (user_age <= 25)
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not including the lower bound.

Comment: ``user_age <= 25`` is also ``True`` for all ages below ``18``, even negative values. You need to extend your check to consider the upper bound (25) **and** the lower bound (18)

Comment: How would I write that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine whether integer is between two other integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/determine-whether-integer-is-between-two-other-integers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code for CHALLENGE ACTIVITY
5.2.1: Detect number range.

> Write an expression that prints "Eligible" if user_age is between 18 and 25 inclusive.
>
> Ex: 17 prints "Ineligible", 18 prints "Eligible".

```
user_age = int(input())

if user_age >= 18 and user_age <= 25 :
    print('Eligible')
else:
    print('Ineligible')
```

Answer (score 0):

user_age = int(input())

if (user_age >= 18) and (user_age != 25):
print('Eligible')
else:
print('Ineligible')

Comment: Please don't copy previous answer.