# my condiotional statement wont work for some wierd reason

Tags: python, conditional-statements

im new to coding and am learning python atm. I was writing this simple code for a discount system and it wont work for some weird reason. pls tell me whats wrong with this code

```
price = (input('Please type the value of your item.'))
if price >= 300:
    price = (price + ((price) * (30/100) )
elif price >= 200 and < 300:
    price = (price + ((price) * (20/100) )
elif price >= 100 and <200:
print('You need to pay' + price + '$ for your item')


    price = (price + ((price) * (10/100) )
```

Comment: `price >= 200 and price < 300` etc., or indeed `200 <= price < 300`

Comment: price is still a string, use `price = int(input())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Whether Integer Is Between Two Other Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/determine-whether-integer-is-between-two-other-integers)

Answer (score 1):

This statement isn't valid:

```
elif price >= 200 and < 300:
```

It would correctly be written as:

```
elif price >= 200 and price < 300:
```

Note that for this to work, `price` needs to be a numeric value; you need to convert your `input()` result to a `float` or `int` before trying anything mathematical with it!

However, specifying `price < 300` isn't necessary in the first place, since this is an `elif` that can only happen if `price >= 300` was false (hence `price < 300` is logically implied to be true).

You can also simplify the arithmetic down; this:

```
price = (price + ((price) * (30/100) )
```

is really just the same (algebraically) as:

```
price = price * (1 + 30/100)
```

which is the same as:

```
price *= 1.3
```

Since you're going to end up with floating point numbers in most cases, you probably want to round this output to 2 decimal places:

```
print('You need to pay' + price + '$ for your item')
```

which you can do easily with an f-string:

```
print(f'You need to pay ${price:.2f} for your item')
```

All together:

```
price = float(input('Please type the value of your item.'))
if price >= 300:
    price *= 1.3
elif price >= 200:
    price *= 1.2
elif price >= 100:
    price *= 1.1
print(f'You need to pay ${price:.2f} for your item')
```

Answer (score 0):

change from this:

```
if price >= 300:
    price = (price + ((price) * (30/100) )
elif price >= 200 and < 300:
    price = (price + ((price) * (20/100) )
elif price >= 100 and <200:
```

to this:

```
if price >= 300:
    price = (price + ((price) * (30/100) )
elif price >= 200 and price < 300:
    price = (price + ((price) * (20/100) )
elif price >= 100 and price < 200:
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide more information to support your answer.