# code does not want to print when i run it

Tags: python

```
def leap():
    year = int(input("enter a number: "))
    if year == range(300,2000):
        print(year/400)
    elif year == range(2001,2024):
         print(year/4)
        

leap()
```

so I am trying to create a function that calculates if the year is a leap year, but it seems it does not want to show the answer of the leap year. there is no error message when I run the code,
also, I am doing this in visual studio code.

Comment: Well, `year != range(300, 2000)`. If you want to check if a value is in a range use `in`: `if year in range(300, 2000):`

Comment: `year` is a single integer.  `range(300,2000)` is a long sequence of integers.  Equality is not possible here; it's not even a meaningful question to ask.  *Containment* of an integer in the sequence is meaningful, but that's written `in`, rather than `==`.  (That should at least get you some output, although your program still wouldn't have much to do with leap years.)

Comment: @jasonharper `range` is not a long sequence, it is a `range` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine whether integer is between two other integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/determine-whether-integer-is-between-two-other-integers) (specifically, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623994/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way simply:

```
def leap():
    year = int(input("enter a number: "))
    if 300 <= year < 2000:
        print(year/400)
    elif 2001 <= year < 2024:
         print(year/4)
        
leap()
```

Or use `in` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `range(300, 2000)` has a type that is different than `year`, in your case an `int`. We can see this in the REPL:

```
>>> r = r(300, 2000)
>>> r
range(300, 2000)
>>> type(r)
<class 'range'>
```

Typically, comparing values of two types will not lead to equality. For this reason `==` is not what you're looking for.

[Ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) are a builtin type in Python, which implements all the [common sequence operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). This is why what you're looking for is:

```
if year in range(300, 2000):
    ...
```

This clause will operate as you expect. Note that it does not scan the list, and is in fact take O(1) time, not O(n).

However, it is probably easier to simply see if your values are within the expected parameters using a direct integer comparison:

```
if year >= 300 and <= 2000:
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

i believe this will determine a leap year

```
def leap():
    year = int(input("enter a number: "))
    if year % 400 == 0:
        print('leap year')
    elif year % 4 ==0 and year % 100 != 0:
        print('leap year')
    else:
         print('not a leap year')
        
leap()
        
leap()
```

Comment: It's worth noting for posterity that it isn't quite this simple.

Comment: problem with the code? Or problem with calendars and time?

Comment: The rule for determining if a year is a leap year is as follows: If it is a multiple of four, it is a leap year, unless it is a multiple of 100, in which case it is not a leap year, unless it is a multiple of 400, in which case it is a leap year.

Comment: Interesting, didnt know that

Comment: So it's a simple `is_leap_year = bool((not year % 4) and (year % 100) or (not year % 400))`.